# Storing subsets of a array

Tags: c, arrays, subset

this program is "calculating" all subsets of the array *source*. I need to store the resulting values in another 2D filed named *polje*. If I just use the `printf("%d %d %d ", source[i][0], source[i][1], source[i][2]);` the code works fine but something fails when it is trying to copy everything into the resulting field. I suppose I am dogin something wrong in the indexing of the array *polje*.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

        int f;
        int i,j;
        int source[2][3] = {{0,3,5},{3,4,2}};
        int currentSubset = 3;
        int polje[8][3];

        for(i=0;i<8;i++){
                for(j=0;j<3;j++){
                        polje[i][j]=0;
                }}
        int tmp;
        while(currentSubset)
        {
                tmp = currentSubset;
                for( i = 0; i<3; i++)
                {
                        if (tmp & 1)
                        {
                                printf("%d %d %d ", source[i][0], source[i][1], source[i][2]); //writes out everything I want
                                polje[currentSubset][0]=source[i][0];
                                polje[currentSubset][1]=source[i][1];
                                polje[currentSubset][2]=source[i][2];
                        }
                        tmp >>= 1;
                }
                printf("\n");
                currentSubset--;
        }

        for(i=0;i<8;i++){
                for(j=0;j<3;j++){
                        printf("%d ", polje[i][j]);
                }printf("\n");}
        return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The output field should be:

```
0 3 5
3 4 2
3 4 2
0 0 0
0 3 5 
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

But instead it is:

```
0 3 5
3 4 2
3 4 2
0 0 0
*0 0 0* 
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

Comment: `int tmp;
        while(currentSubset)
        {
                tmp = currentSubset;` looks like bad style to me. Coul be done simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tmp` is a bit mask with only two bits, so the inner loop should be `for ( i = 0; i < 2; i++ )`.

Also the correct index into the `polje` array is `polje[currentSubset * 2 + i][0]` since each `subset` in `polje` takes two spaces and `i` is either 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have a logic error. Your loop's skeleton is:

```
currentSubset = 3;
while ( currentSubset )
{
// ...
    polje[currentSubset][...] = ...;
// ...
    currentSubset--;
}
```

So you never write to any rows except the first three.

Comment: oh, yes, now it's obvious,any ideas on how to store the array?

Comment: Make sure you can do the algorithm you want by hand (e.g. on paper, or in your head). Then break that down into a list of baby steps that you want your program to do; and then check that your program implements each of those steps.